# Achitecture Check for CentOS

Tags: centos

If i enter the command :

```
arch
```

And get the results :

```
X86_64
```

Then does this mean i can install and run both 32 & 64 bits application on my CentOS machine ?

Comment: FYI, Arch Linux is a distribution of Linux, not architecture as in a CPU family. I edited the tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 bit **x86** applications can run on x86_64 CentOS, yes.  List available packages of that architecture with `yum list *.i?86`